# Composable doesn't recompose on state change

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why does this not recompose, despite state changing.

```
@Composable
fun IngredientsScreen() {

    var numberOfIngredients by remember {mutableStateOf(1)}

    Box(

    ){
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ){
            for (i in 0 until numberOfIngredients){
                IngredientInputBox(
                    onClick = {
                        numberOfIngredients++
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IngredientInputBox() is just a composable that contains a text field and a "+" symbol that is clickable, ideally when the symbol is pressed, a new text field would appear beneath it

```
@Composable
fun IngredientInputBox(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
    ){
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                text = newText
            },
            label = {Text(text = stringResource(R.string.addNewIngredient))},
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.3F)
                .weight(1f)
        )
        Text(
            text = "+",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {onClick}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is likely inside `IngredientInputBox()`. Can you post that code? By the way, for simpler code, you can replace `for (i in 0 until numberOfIngredients)` with `repeat(numberOfIngredients)`.

Comment: As @Tenfour04 points out, this works if, for example, `IngredientInputBox` is just a `Text` with a clickable event handler. Can provide the implementation of `IngredientInputBox`?

Comment: @Tenfour04  I added the code you requested, however there seems to be an answer so I'll check that.

Comment: @chuckj  I added the code you requested, however there seems to be an answer so I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's wrong with your implementation. This code:

```
modifier = Modifier
    .clickable {onClick}
```

Makes it so your button, when clicked, does absolutely nothing. The code in your lambda is what is called when the button is clicked, and it just declares the name of the click listener without doing anything with it.

You could fix it using

```
modifier = Modifier
    .clickable {onClick()}
```

or

```
modifier = Modifier
    .clickable(onClick = onClick)
```

Comment: Oh yeah... I'm just stupid

Comment: Small note: you need to specify the name of the parameter since the `onClick` is the last parameter `Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick)`.